# Algorithm design: θ(f(n)) - help explaining my answer

Tags: algorithms

I am studying algorithm design and need some help explaining my (correct) answer  to the following question:

> Assume that $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$. Can we say that for every input size $n$,
>   our algorithm will perform a maximum of $10n^3$ operations? Why?

My answer, is as follows:

> No, because by definition:  $T(n)$ is $\Theta(f(n))$ only if $T(n)$ is both $O(n)$
>   and $\Omega(n)$.
>
> i.e. $c_1 \cdot f(n) \le T(n) \le c_2 \cdot f(n)$

I was told that whilst the answer is correct, the explanation is not. Can somebody explain to my why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear to me why you think that your answer *does* explain why the statement is false, so I don’t know just how helpful the following will be.

In order to justify your assertion that the statement is false, you need to demonstrate that it really is possible for an algorithm to be $\Theta(n^2)$ and still perform more than $10n^3$ operations for at least some values of $n$. You’ve merely stated what it means for an algorithm to be $\Theta(n^2)$ without offering any explanation of how to use this explanation to show that such a counterexample exists.

What you could have done instead is show that if $T(n)=10^7+n^2$, then $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n^2)$, but clearly $T(n)>10n^3$ for $n\le 100$.

Comment: Thanks! Mhhh, my reasoning was as follows: 
If T(n) is Θ(f(n)) then, by definition, this means that f(n) is "sandwiched" between an upper and lower bound. Therefore, we can't have more than f(n) executions. If we would, then T(n) would not be Θ(f(n)) as it would be bounded by something higher than f(n)...Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1796218: But that argument works *against* what you’re trying to show: it’s the fact that $T$ is sandwiched between fixed multiples of $n^2$ that leads some people (incorrectly) to think that there *is* some absolute upper bound on $T(n)$ that’s good for all functions that are $\Theta(n^2)$. The point of this question is that there is no such absolute upper bound: anything that we try can be broken by a $\Theta(n^2)$ function for an arbitrarily large finite number of values of $n$.

Comment: Original: Ah, thanks! Now I understand.

Edit: Actually, no, wait... :-)

Comment: @user1796218: You’re welcome!

Comment: Actually, sorry. Reading your response again: I didn't understand haha. 

...what do you mean by "can be broken by a Θ(n$^2$) function for an arbitrarily large finite number of values of n"?

So, you are saying that just because a function is Θ(n$^2$),  does not mean that there doesn't exist a larger bound for T(n)?

Comment: @user1796218: I’m saying that no matter what function $f(n)$ and positive integer $m$ you pick, there is function $T(n)$ that is $\Theta(n^2)$ but nevertheless has the property that $T(n)>f(n)$ for all $n\le m$. The function $f$ can grow much faster than $n^2$; it doesn’t matter. Whether a function is $\Theta(n^2)$ depends only on the long-term behavior of the function.

Comment: OK, now I understand! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1796218: You’re very welcome!